# How to correctly model self-referencing multi-parent relationship using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to model the following self-referencing person class in EF6.

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? MotherId { get; set; }
    public Person Mother { get; set; }

    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public Person Father { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext looks like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(m => m.Mother)
        .WithMany(c => c.Children)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.MotherId);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.Father)
        .WithMany(c => c.Children)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.FatherId);
}
```

When trying to add a person to the database using the following code:

```
db.People.Add(new Person { Name = "Jane Doe" });
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains no matching element

**What does this error mean, and how do I correct it?** Optionally, is there a better way to model this object (ex: using subclass of Mother:Person and Father:Person)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with the following solution that generates a clean database and allows for greater flexibility when adding relationships:

```
public interface IParent
{
    ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? MotherId { get; set; }
    public Female Mother { get; set; }

    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public Male Father { get; set; }
}

public class Male : Person, IParent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Female : Person, IParent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext only contains:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Female> Females { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Male> Males { get; set; }
```

And the resulting database looks like this:

```
ID  Name    MotherId    FatherId    Discriminator
1   Jane    NULL        NULL        Female
2   John    NULL        NULL        Male
3   Jimmy   1           2           Male
4   Jenn    1           2           Female
```

This solution also gives the flexibility of adding relationships in multiple ways:

```
mom.Children.Add(son); // or
son.Mother = mom;
```

Comment: how do you specify the FKs?

Comment: You don't need to - EF uses the PK of the related entity by default, and by convention this is the prop named ID or ClassNameID.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following. Although it might not fit your 'In Entity Framework' requirement

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? MotherId { get; set; }
    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
}

public Class RelationFinder
{
    Public Person GetMother(IEnumerable<Person> people, Person child)
    {
        return people.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id = child.MotherId);
    }

    Public Person GetFather(...

    Public IEnumerable GetChildern(...
}
```

Comment: This is a good option, but I'm trying to stick with EF's built in magic and write as little additional code as possible.

Comment: unfortunately EFs magic dosnt work too well with nullable FKs and self referencing. maybe of you change the IEnumerables to IQueryables you can get the same effect?